# GitLab API - search project

Tags: gitlab-api

I'm using:

`GET https://localhost/api/v4/search?scope=projects&search=test`

to find project named "test" , but I get not only project named "test" but "qtest", "testot" or "test1" too.

Is it possible to get only exact name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [Projects API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/projects.html#search-for-projects-by-name), no. It will return all projects that contain your search string, but you should be able to filter the results once you retrieve it.

The available options are `sort` and `order_by`. You can order by the fields `id`, `name`, `created_at`, and `last_activity_at`

Answer (score 2):

One may use `jq` to filter the returned results from a fuzzy search:

```bash
project_name="test"

curl --silent --show-error --location \
  "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/search?scope=projects&search=${project_name}" \
  --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: ${GITLAB_COM_API_PRIVATE_TOKEN}" | jq \
  --raw-output --arg project_name "${project_name}" '.[] | \
  select(.name == $project_name)'
```

Of course, this returns 12 projects. Which one is mine?

It is far better if you can include a namespace.

```bash
project_path_with_namespace="$username/test"

curl --silent --show-error --location \
  "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/search?scope=projects&search=${project_path_with_namespace}" \
  --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: ${GITLAB_COM_API_PRIVATE_TOKEN}" | jq \
  --arg path_with_namespace "${project_path_with_namespace}" '.[] | \
  select(.path_with_namespace == $path_with_namespace)'
```

Now the search is not fuzzy and will always return a precise result so long as such a project exists at that path.